# React JS-Second Route tag not working in App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

PFB the files and project structure

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { TeamPage } from './pages/TeamPage';
import { MatchPage } from './pages/MatchPage';

function App() {
  return (
   <div className = "App"> 
    <Router>
      <Switch>


        <Route exact path="/teams/:teamName/mathes/:year">
          <MatchPage />
        </Route>  
 
        <Route  path="/teams/:teamName" >
          <TeamPage />
        </Route>

       

      </Switch>

    </Router> 
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TeamPage.js

```
import { React,useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { MatchDetailCard } from '../components/MatchDetailCrd';
import { MatchSmallCard } from '../components/MatchSmallCard';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
export const TeamPage = () =>{

const [team,setTeam] = useState({matches :[]});
const { teamName } = useParams();
useEffect(
    
    ()=>{
        const fetchMatches = async()=>{
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/team/${teamName}`);
            const data = await response.json();
           // console.log(data);
            setTeam(data);
            
        };
        fetchMatches();

    },[teamName]
);
if(!team || !team.teamName) {
    return <h1>Team Not Found</h1>
}

  return (
      <div className = "TeamPage"> 
          <h1>{team.teamName}</h1>
          <h3>Letest Matches</h3>
          <MatchDetailCard teamName={team.teamName} match = {team.matches[0]}/>
          {team.matches.slice(1).map(match => <MatchSmallCard teamName={team.teamName} match={match}/>)}
         
         
      </div>
    
   
  );
}
```

MatchPage.js

```
import { React,useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { MatchDetailCard } from '../components/MatchDetailCrd';
import { MatchSmallCard } from '../components/MatchSmallCard';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

export const MatchPage = () =>{

  return (
      <div className = "MatchPage"> 
            <h1>Match ------------------------------------------------ Page</h1>
      </div>
    
  );
}
```

MatchDetailCard.js

i

```
mport { React} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const MatchDetailCard = ({teamName,match}) =>{
if(!match) return null;
const otherTeam= match.team1===teamName ? match.team2 : match.team1;
const otherTeamRoute =`/teams/${otherTeam}`;
    
  return (
   
      <div className = "MatchDetailCard"> 
         <h3>Detail Card</h3>
         <p><Link to={otherTeamRoute}>vs {otherTeam}</Link></p>
         <h1>{match.date}</h1>
         <h3>{match.venue}</h3>
         <h3>winner is {match.winner} and win by {match.result}</h3>
      </div>
    
   
  );
}
```

MatchSmallCard.js

```
import { React} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const MatchSmallCard = ({teamName,match}) =>{
if(!match) return null;
const otherTeam= match.team1===teamName ? match.team2 : match.team1;
const otherTeamRoute =`/teams/${otherTeam}`;
    
  return (
   
      <div className = "MatchSmallCard"> 
          <h3>Match Details</h3>
         <h1><Link to={otherTeamRoute}>vs {otherTeam}</Link></h1>
         <p>winner is {match.winner} and win by {match.result}</p>
      
      </div>
    
   
  );
}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

When i changed the url the second router supposed to work. But it show same page
see below
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Please Help. iam a beginer in react.

Comment: add exact in second route and then try

Comment: `<Route exact  path="/teams/:teamName" ><TeamPage /></Route>`

Comment: can you remove the first router tag see if the second one works?

Comment: `<Route exact path="/teams/:teamName" component={TeamPage}/>`

Comment: I did this. Second Route Page is Not displaying.

Comment: Thank u for your comments. There was a Spelling mistake in the second Router.

Comment: The Issue is Resolved